# Validation not accepting decimals using Joi node.js

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I have added validation for some parameters using joi for this i need validation for point parameter to accept decimal.

This is my validation code

```
const userSchema = Joi.object({
point: Joi.number().max(150).required(),
});
```

In the above code, i want to accept the data to be decimal in the place of number.Can any one know to wrote the code to accept decimals.

Comment: Can you please provide the error that you get?

Comment: Joi.number(...).float is not a function.This the eroor i got

Comment: Joi library doesn't have a `float` function. `number()` should accept all types of numbers including integer and decimals. If you still get an error without using `float`, can you please provide that here?

Comment: using number() i am not getting any error

Comment: If you're not getting errors, then what is the issue?

Comment: i have asked is there any way to use decimal instead of number because the input i need to give is decimal type, but as u say i am going to use number type.

Answer (score 0):

Support for validating floating point numbers was removed from Joi a [long time ago](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/112) because it's inherently useless.

Numbers in JavaScript are always stored as double precision floating point numbers so whether the payload contains `2` or `2.0000000`, by the time the value is assigned to a variable, JavaScript sees the same thing.

Joi has a [`precision()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#numberprecisionlimit) method you can use to specify the maximum number of decimal places allowed which you may or may not find useful.

For whatever reason you specifically need floating point numbers you'll either need to create your own custom validation using [`.extend()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#extendextension) or accept integers in the payload and do some sort of casting server side.